# using for loops in R language

Tags: r

thank you ahead of time

Having my students write code to find slope of the secant line
I'm having trouble in a for loop when the interval is [-1,1] because `i` can't become negative.  Here's a piece of my code:

```
#delta.x

a = 0       # if I change to a = -1 doesnt work
b = 1
n = 6
delta.x = (b-a)/n
delta.x


        ##  results:  .166 ##

# Finding the [lower,upper] numbers of the sub-intervals:  over [0,1]

x = rep(0,7)
x

for (i in 1:n) {
  x[i+1] = x[i] + delta.x
 }

x
```

Answer (score 1):

When I change the line `a = 0` to `a = -1`, the code runs fine. So, I assume that when you say "it doesn't work" you mean it doesn't give you the output you expect, right?

If I correctly understand what you want, the problem is that you've initialized `x[1]` to be 0, but you really want it to be `a`. Consider putting `x[1] <- a` right before your `for` loop.

Please let me know if that was not the problem.